# How to keep an NSTimer running in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I want to make a countdown a timer that will keep running when in background. That's the code I'm using:

```
- (void)timerRun
{
    secondsCount--;

    int minutes = secondsCount / 60;
    int seconds = secondsCount - (minutes * 60);

    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minutes, seconds];
    self.timerLabel.text = timerOutput;

    if (secondsCount == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        self.timerLabel.text = @"Time out";
    }
}

- (void)startTimer
{
    secondsCount = 120;

    if (secondsCount == 0) {
        [timer invalidate];
        self.timerLabel.text = @"None";
    }
    else {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

How do I make it that the timer will keep running in the background, and preventing from the timer to restart everytime the app restarts? Thanks.

Comment: when you say running in the background, you mean you would like it to run 100% of the time?

Comment: not sure if there is a way to do that, but one option you have is when the app is going out of focus, save the NSDate it went out of focus to nsuserdefaults, then when the app reloads you can load that NSDAte and do the math to calculate how much time has passed and set the new timer appropriately

Comment: @nycynik What do you mean by 100% of the time? I want it to run in the background so for example if I close the app at 1 minute left, and 30 secs passes and I reopen the app, the label will show 30 secs and keep counting

Answer (score 0):

You can't it's prohibited and bad practice. NSTimer needs a run loop to count you should not have that in background, so NSTimer are stoped in background. Do as @Dan Dosch says. Records the timestamp when you go into background and compare it with the timestamp when you came back in foreground. You just have to update your view in viewWillAppear it will do the job.